# Kestral, IIS and Port Exhaustion

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, .net, elastic-beanstalk

Deploying a .NET CORE web-socket app via AWS Beanstalk.  By default this uses IIS as a reverse proxy.  Unfortunately reverse proxies use ports to do their work, leading to port exhaustion.

How can we configure IIS to scale to 100,000 connections and beyond?

Alternatively how can we configure AWS Beanstalk to run kestrel directly without IIS?